# difference between import * and from tkinter import message box?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter, python-import

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
```

I wanted to know that what is the difference between these two.
doesn't import * imports all the modules and function from tkinter to the projects then why do we need to import messagebox seperately.

Comment: The difference is that in the first case you're importing *everything* contained in tkinter module (which you shouldn't do) and in the second case you're importing a specific class that you need.

Comment: `from tkinter import *` imports all function/classes that are defined in the `__init__.py` or the modules defined in the `__all__=[ ]` in the `__init__.py`. The reason you are not able to import MessageBox class or any other class from the messagebox using `from tkinter import *` is because the authors decided not to include it in the `__init__.py` file. `from tkinter import *` is only for convenience for the users. If widgets classes were defined in their own modules and not included in __init__.py you would then have to import something like `from tkinter.label import Label`

Comment: Read about python packages from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Comment: whilst wildcard imports are allowed, for clarity it is best to avoid then:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0)

Answer (score 0):

In `from tkinter import *`, you can refer to each and every thing in `tkinter` module. Because it imports the names directly into the local namespace, it creates the potential for conflicts if you import things from many modules. Therefore, the `from tkinter import *` is discouraged.

In `from tkinter import messagebox`, which imports just the `messagebox` into the local namespace, not everything in `tkinter`. This is better because if you list the names you import, you know exactly what you are importing and it's easier to avoid name conflicts.

Answer (score -1):

if you've imported all using import *, you no longer need imports for specific modules, but this will use more memory than just importing specific modules

Comment: The more important reason why `import *` is an anti-pattern is the high potential for namespace conflicts.